# How to Configure a Shell Script to continue after Reboot

Tags: linux, shell

I am currently trying to install SAP servers on Linux and I've run into a bit of a situation. Script must follow below steps

1. Set swap size
2. Reboot server
3. Perform SAP installation.

So I have created the single script which will set the swap space & do the installation but not sure how I can add the reboot feature in it. I read some blogs which refers to use /etc/rc.local but it seems in this case I will have to create two scripts:

Script 1: It will set the value for swap space & then add the calling of second script in rc.local

Script 2: It will have syntax to perform SAP installation.

is there any way that I use single script to for complete setup??

Comment: Your script can certainly look at how it's called, whether a flag is set, etc. and decide whether or not to run the pre-reboot section based on same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a swapfile, a reboot is not required:

```
# Create swapfile of 2G
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=2048
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile

# Run SAP installation

# If you don't need the additional swap after the installation ...
swapoff /swapfile # Might take a while
rm /swapfile
```

Comment: Really appreciate your response. We are setting up swap space on VM available in Azure cloud & it requires system reboot to activate swap.

Comment: As long it is Linux it does **not** require a reboot to add / remove swapspace. Just run `free -g` after adding the swapfile to see.

Comment: Azure has already given mount point /mnt/resource or /mnt for setting swap space. To create a swap file in this directory that's defined by the ResourceDisk.MountPoint parameter, we have to update the /etc/waagent.conf by setting some parameters & then need to take restart to activate them. Therefore reboot is mandatory in my scenario.

Comment: If the point is just to have additional swap space during the SAP installation this does work without a reboot (if you have 2G free disk space), trust me. I mean Azure or not, at the end it is Linux. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I just tried it & it worked fine.But I want to utilize already given mount point.

Comment: I've just read the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4010058/how-to-add-a-swap-file-in-linux-azure-virtual-machines). I mean what stops you from using the swapfile, as I showed, during the installation, perform all actions (including the changes in /etc/waagent.conf) and reboot after the full installation has been completed. After the reboot the system will pick up the swapspace from /mnt/resources, the changes I showed are not persistent.

Comment: so this is how scripts suppose to run. Right?

1. Modify parameters
2. Add swap (like you suggested)
3. Do the SAP Installation
4. Reboot Linux

Comment: Yeah, exactly. That should work. I bet the reboot (as recommended in the documentation) can also be avoided. But Azure == Microsoft. And you know, a reboot is always good for a Windows System ;)